# EF Core - import entity with relationships to entities that dont exist yet

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I encountered this somehow special task. My model looks like this

```
public class Bot
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public StoryItem StartItem { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Story> Stories { get; set; }
}

public class Story
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int BotId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<StoryItem> Items { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<StoryLink> Links { get; set; }
}

public class StoryItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int StoryId { get; set; }
}

public class StoryLink
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int StoryId { get; set; }

    public int SourceItemId { get; set; }

    public StoryItem SourceItem { get; set; }

    public int TargetItemId { get; set; }

    public StoryItem TargetItem { get; set; }
}
```

In my application, there is an option to export Bot to json (with all its properties).

The problematic part is to implement the import functionality. Is there a way to import bot entity, with all its relations to entities, that dont exist yet (they need to be created during the import process)? Can EF do it somehow intelligently?

One way would be to import everything one by one and map the old IDs to new ones, but I hope there would be a more sophisticated way.

I would appreciate any advice, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - replace `IEnumerable<T>` with `List<T>`.

EF can save related entities.

```
vat bot = new Bot();
var story = new Story();
bot.Stories.Add(story);

dbContext.Set<Bot>().Add(bot);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: First of all, `IEnumerable<T>` is just fine in EF Core. Second, you don't seem to understand the actual OP issue - their model has circular relationship `Bot` <-> `StoryItem`, which (like chicken and egg) cannot be handled automatically with single `SaveChanges`.

Comment: @IvanStoev are you saying it is not possible in a simple way? I hoped that maybe EF would somehow map the old IDs to the new ones automatically.

Comment: @merlinko The problem is not with Ids. Actually if they are auto-generated, you need to clear them all before calling `Add`. The new ids will be generated and correctly mapped from navigation properties. But `StoryItem` cannot be created w/o Story, and Story cannot be create w/o Bot, hence new Bot cannot have StoryItem. You need to set that property to null, then `SaveChanges` then set it back and do `SaveChanges` again.

Comment: @IvanStoev if this would be the only manual step it would be very okay :) but how would  I know, which StoryItem is the one, that is supposed to be on Bot?

Comment: @merlinko By storing the original value of the property in variable? Or if the deserializer does not preserve references, find it manually by Id in the deserialized object graph, store it in variable and use it later (when it's already created in the db).

Comment: @IvanStoev I see, thank you very much, i will definitely try this :)